# Android App crash when Data deleted from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, crash

I am working on a app but when I delete data from firebase my app crashed. I used 2 screens in this procedure. User search's customer data (customer is search by the word which is child in firebase) from 1st screen and through Intent Filter string is passes to 2nd screen. When I press delete button my app crashed and show me the toast of 1st screen where I write a check **Data not Exists**.

**Search Code in 1st Screen**

```
            database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Not Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            searchText.setText("");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data  Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(deleteUpdate.this, updateData.class);
                            intent.putExtra("value", s);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });
```

**Intent Code**

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
            String str = intent.getStringExtra("value");
```

**Delete Button Code**

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CustomerInfo").child(str);
                        db.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Can you post your full activity code as well as the error log?